# Undefined references even though library is linking and it contains correct symbols

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I am trying to compile my executable with this line from my Makefile:

```
g++-8.1.0 -Wall -Wextra -pthread -std=c++17 -ggdb3 -I/usr/local/include ./src/barometer.o ./src/serial.o ./src/ptpcontroller.o ./src/stream.o ./src/helper.o ./src/thetav.o ./src/gps.o ./src/flightcontroller.o ./src/gui.o ./src/maneuvers.o ./src/main.o ./src/fcinterface.o ./libs/NemaTode/src/NumberConversion.o ./libs/NemaTode/src/NMEAParser.o ./libs/NemaTode/src/GPSFix.o ./libs/NemaTode/src/NMEACommand.o ./libs/NemaTode/src/GPSService.o ./libs/ptpcam/ptpcam.o -o halo -L/usr/local/lib -lwiringPi -lrt -lpigpio -lncurses -lptp2 -lusb
```

And I get lots of undefined reference errors like this:

```
./libs/ptpcam/ptpcam.o: In function `init_ptp_usb(_PTPParams*, _PTP_USB*, usb_device*)':
/home/pi/ProjectHaloDrone/RPiCM3/libs/ptpcam/ptpcam.cpp:322: undefined reference to `ptp_usb_sendreq(_PTPParams*, _PTPContainer*)'
```

Even though all these symbols are in the libptp2 library that I am linking against with -lptp2:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ProjectHaloDrone/RPiCM3 $ nm -g /usr/local/lib/libptp2.so | grep ptp_usb_sendreq
00002d3c T ptp_usb_sendreq
```

I am very confused why the linker thinks the symbols aren't defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that linker reports unresolved external symbols as `ptp_usb_sendreq(_PTPParams*, _PTPContainer*)` means that those symbols are mangled in C++ way (otherwise, function arguments would not be visible).

At the same time, `nm` reports the symbol as `ptp_usb_sendreq`, which means, it is not mangled.

Most likely solution: check and make sure your function signature (likely in a header file) is wrapped in `extern "C"` specifier.

Comment: This was exactly right, I forgot the extern "C". Thank you!!